# AdWhirl ads sometimes change 5 times per second

Tags: android, admob, ads, adwhirl

I am having an issue with adwhirl ads. I have added AdMob and InMobi ads to my app. the ads show and everything is ok except sometimes when i lock and then unlock the phone again or for no apparent reason the ads start changing, showing a couple of ads per second, for at least 3 or 4 seconds, then it goes back to normal.

anyone else has this issue? how do i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I've had this issue before, and I think it has something to do with Adwhirl's SDK - though I would first check your code to make sure you weren't accidentally loading multiple adwhirl instances onResume or something. Even after I fixed my code to verify I only ever had one instance, I still had this error that I could not procedurally reproduce (it would appear seemingly at random).